# Inno Setup download from nexus server

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup, nexus

I try make setup with will connect to my nexus server and give in installation Possibility chose with version install. To download from repo I use that plugin: https://mitrichsoftware.wordpress.com/inno-setup-tools/inno-download-plugin/

I can connect which is successful and download indicated, but don't have idea how to list in installer version of apps and then install.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague.

So I can only similarly vaguely suggest you to:

- Publish a file in the repository with a list of versions and make the installer download it and present it to the user as a menu/selection;
- Or use a list of files/folders in the repository, instead of the explicit list file.